# How to transform seq into vector without so much verbosity?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to implement reorder functionality for a vector of maps. For now, I want to understand how to move un-nested items inside the vector, before I tackle nested vectors, etc.

Trying to learn clojure on the way...

Here's what I came up with:

```
(defn split-at' [idx v]
  [(subvec v 0 idx) (subvec v idx)])

(defn my-reorder [lst start-pos end-pos]
  (let [item-to-move (get lst start-pos)
        spliced (remove-from-vec lst start-pos)
        [left-side right-side] (split-at' end-pos spliced)]
    (vec
      (flatten
        (conj [] (if (empty? left-side) [] left-side) item-to-move (if (empty? right-side) [] right-side)))
    )))

(my-reorder items 7 6)
```

If I don't do the whole checkups and flattening, I get vectors wrapping various elements which is unwanted.
Here's how sample data looks like:

```
(def items [
         {:id "1" :text "HELLO I am First"}
         {:id "2" :text "RENDER IT!"}
         {:id "3" :children [{:id "4" :text "Im a child"}
                            {:id "5" :text "Im special!"}
                            {:id "6" :children [{:id 7 :text "I am so deep !!!"}]}]}
         {:id "8" :text "GoodBye I am last"}
         {:id "9" :children [{:id "10" :text "I am Number 10!"}]}
         {:id "13" :text "GoodBye I am last"}
          {:id "14" :text "GoodBye I am last"}
         {:id "15" :text "GoodBye I am last"}
         ])
```

Is there a more concise way to deal with this?
Ultimately I want to get back the same vector just with new order.

I tried flattening without doing nested if-checks and resulted in mixes results.

Comment: I assume that the sample data is the input. Could you please add the corresponding output that you expect? It's hard to understand what you want by the description alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this will work:

```
(defn upd [from to data]
  (vec (mapcat (fn [i x] (cond (= i from) []                               
                               (= i to) (if (< from to) 
                                          [x (data from)]
                                          [(data from) x])
                               :else [x]))
               (range)
               data)))
```

it just passes through indexed collection, remving item at `from`, prepending it to the part of seq started with `to` index:

```
(upd 2 0 [1 2 3 4 5])
;; [3 1 2 4 5]

(upd 0 2 [1 2 3 4 5])
;; [2 3 1 4 5]
```

maybe it's not the most elegant of them all, but at least it is done in one pass, and doesn't involve flattening, which is almost always not the best idea (at least in your case)

also, you can avoid double pass (mapcat + vec) by using transducer:

```
(defn upd [from to data]
  (into [] (mapcat (fn [i] (cond (= i from) []                               
                                 (= i to) (if (< from to) 
                                            [(data i) (data from)]
                                            [(data from) (data i)])
                                 :else [(data i)])))
        (range (count data))))
```

Comment: Was about to suggest this. :) A potential improvement would be to use transducers: `(into [] (comp (keep-indexed ...) cat) data)`.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question asks one thing but the body asks another.

> How to transform seq into vector without so much verbosity?

Just call `vec` on the seq.

> how to move un-nested items inside the vector

Judging by the signature and the name of `my-reorder`, you want for two items in a vector to exchange places.

Vectors are associative collections, so you can do it trivially like this:

```
(defn my-reorder [v idx1 idx2]
  (assoc v idx1 (v idx2) idx2 (v idx1)))
```

Comment: I've learned something new today, thank you. However, I don't want them to exchange positions, but rather to move one item. For example, in vector of [1,2,3,4,5] I want to be able to move 0-idx to idx2; [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]

Comment: @BoristofuPovolotsky If you use `remove-from-vec` only in that function, consider the answer by @leetwinski. Otherwise, your original function is alright, but you can replace that `(vec ...)` with `(vec (concat left-side item-to-move right-side))`.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by splitting the input sequence in three parts:

- A left part that is unchanged
- A middle part that is rotated by one step to the left or right
- A right part that is unchaged.

Something like this:

```
(defn my-reorder3 [lst a b]
  (let [shift (compare a b)
        l (min a b)
        u (inc (max a b))
        n (- u l)]
    (into (subvec lst 0 l)
          cat
          [(mapv #(nth lst (+ l (mod (- % shift) n))) (range n))
           (subvec lst u)])))


(my-reorder3 [:a :b :c :d :e] 0 2)
;; => [:b :c :a :d :e]

(my-reorder3 [:a :b :c :d :e] 2 0)
;; => [:c :a :b :d :e]

(my-reorder3 [:a :b :c :d :e] 2 2)
;; => [:a :b :c :d :e]
```